# WPF DockPanel not showing a Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, dockpanel

I am using a DockPanel and I wanted to add a vertical scrollbar however using the XAML code below the vertical scrollbar is not showing:

```
<DockPanel Margin="10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  
     <RichTextBox BorderBrush="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
     <ListView Margin="10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
          <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="DetailsGridView">
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RichTextBox/>                                      

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RichTextBox/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
       </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

Also the ListView needs to have a vertical scrollbar as well.
Can you suggest if the above code needs to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: you can put DockPanel inside `<ScrollViewer>` to have a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!